# Написал сервер на Node JS. На локалке работает отлично. На сервере не может найти файлы .css, .js, .png и др

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, хостинг, localhost

Сервер на локалке: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер на хостинге: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Код сервера (Node JS):
    // Работает - сука не трожь!
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const os = require('os');
const moment = require('moment');
const PORT = process.env.PORT ?? 3000;
const ip = require('ip');
const readline = require('readline');
const util = require('util');
const lineReader = require('line-reader');
const app = require("express");

let logger = 600;

// let info = new Userinfo();
// let time = moment().format('yyyy-mm-dd:hh:mm:ss');
let time = new Date();
let logtime = "["+time+"] ";
let datetime = new Date();
let seconds = datetime.getSeconds();
let minutes = datetime.getMinutes();
let hours = datetime.getHours();
let date = datetime.getDate();
let month = datetime.getMonth() + 1;
let year = datetime.getFullYear();
let consoletext = "\x1b[0m";
let customtext = "\x1b[35m";
let version = "0.0.5";
let index = 'index.html';
let indexfolder = 'web';
let serverfile = path.basename(__filename);
setInterval(log, logger * 1000)

// var ifaces = require('os').networkInterfaces();
// var adresses = Object.keys(ifaces).reduce(function (result, dev) {
//     return result.concat(ifaces[dev].reduce(function (result, details) {
//       return result.concat(details.family === 'IPv4' && !details.internal ? [details.address] : []);
//     }, []));
// });

// const server = http.createServer();

// fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, html){
//     if (err) throw err;

// server.on("request", (req, res) =>{
//     console.log("\x1b[0m", "IP:"+"\x1b[31m", req.ip+"\x1b[0m","отправил запрос: ", "\x1b[35m"+req.url, "\x1b[0m");
//     if (req.url === "/"){
//         res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
//         res.end(html);
//     }
// });

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, indexfolder, req.url === '/' ? index : req.url);
    function information(){
      var reqip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
      var ip = reqip.slice(0);
      var user = req.headers["user-agent"];
      var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
      var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
      var hours = new Date().getHours();
      var year = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
      var month = new Date().getUTCMonth() + 1;
      var day = new Date().getDate();
      var language = req.headers["accept-language"];
      var other = req.headers;
      // var Country = geo ? geo.country: "Unknown"
      // var Region = geo ? geo.region: "Unknown"

      if(minutes < 10) minutes = "0"+minutes;
      else minutes = minutes;

      if(seconds < 10) seconds = "0"+seconds;
      else seconds = seconds;

      if(month < 10) month = "0"+month;
      else month = month;

      if(day < 10) day = "0"+day;
      else day = day;
      var newtime = "["+hours+":"+minutes+"."+seconds+"]";
      var newdate = "["+year+"."+month+"."+day+"]"

      function updateusers(){
        console.log(consoletext, " ------ ", consoletext);
        console.log("\x1b[32m", newdate+" "+newtime+"\x1b[0m","OS:"+"\x1b[33m", user);
        console.log("\x1b[32m", newdate+" "+newtime+"\x1b[0m","IP:"+"\x1b[31m", ip);
        console.log("\x1b[32m", newdate+" "+newtime+"\x1b[0m","Language:"+"\x1b[36m", language);
        // console.log("\x1b[32m", newdate+" "+newtime+"\x1b[0m","Other:"+"\x1b[30m", other);
        console.log("\x1b[32m", newdate+" "+newtime+"\x1b[0m","Отправил запрос: ", "\x1b[35m"+req.url, consoletext);
        console.log(consoletext, " ------ ", consoletext);
      }
      updateusers();
    }
    const ext = path.extname(filePath)
    let contentType = 'text/html'
  
    switch (ext) {
      case '.css':
        contentType = 'text/css'
        break
      case '.js':
        contentType = 'text/javascript'
        break
      default:
        contentType = 'text/html'
    }
  
    if (!ext) {
      filePath += '.html'
    }
  
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
      if (err) {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, indexfolder, 'error.html'), (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end('Error');
          } else {
            
            res.writeHead(200, {
               'Content-Type': contentType
            })
            res.end(data);
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': contentType
        });
        res.end(content);
        information();
      }
    });
  });

server.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(logtime+"\x1b[32m","Сервер работает"+"\x1b[0m","на порте"+"\x1b[34m", PORT, consoletext)
});

console.log("\x1b[0m", "Название файла: ", "\x1b[36m", path.basename(__filename));
console.log("\x1b[0m", "Имя директории: ", "\x1b[36m", path.dirname(__filename));
console.log("\x1b[0m", "Расширение файла: ", "\x1b[36m", path.extname(__filename));
console.log("\x1b[0m", "IP-Адрес Сервера: ", "\x1b[36m", ip.address());
console.log("\x1b[0m", "Версия сервера: ", "\x1b[33m", version);

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var commands = {
    exit: "Выключение сервера",
    stop: "Выключение сервера",
    port: "Открытый порт",
    ver: "Версия консоли",
    index: "Индексная страница",
    indexfolder: "Папка с сайтом",
    log: "Сохранение лога консоли в отдельный файл",
    datetime: "Узнать текущее время по версии сервера",
    clear: "Очистить содержимое консоли"
}

function log(){
  console.log(customtext, logtime+"Начинаю процесс логирования...", consoletext);
  fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, 'logs'), (err) =>{
    if (err) fs.mkdir('logs', err => {if (err) console.log(logtime+"\x1b[32m","Папка найдена!"); newlogfile();})
    else{
      console.log(logtime+"\x1b[31m","Папка не найдена!", consoletext);
      console.log(logtime+"Создаю папку логирования");
      log();
    }
  }); 
}

function newlogfile(){
let log = date+"."+month+"."+year+"--"+seconds+"."+minutes+"."+hours+"_logfile.txt";
let newfile = fs.writeFile("newlog.txt", 'loged', function(err){
  if (err) console.log(logtime+"\x1b[31m", "Ошибка при создании файла", consoletext);
  else{
    console.log("\x1b[32m","Файл успешно обновлён!", consoletext);
    fs.rename('newlog.txt', 'logs/'+log, err =>{
      if (err) console.log("\x1b[31m", "Не удалось переместить файл");
      // console.log("\x1b[34m", "Файл успешно перемещён в папку", consoletext);
    })
  }
})
}

process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
  let t = text.trim()
  if (t === 'exit') {process.exit();}
  else if(t === 'stop'){process.exit();}
  else if(t === 'help'){console.log(commands, consoletext)}
  else if(t === 'port'){console.log(PORT)}
  else if(t === 'ver'){console.log(customtext, version, consoletext)}
  else if(t === 'index'){console.log(customtext, index, consoletext)}
  else if(t === 'indexfolder'){console.log(customtext, indexfolder, consoletext)}
  // else if(t === 'save'){serverfile > newlogfile.txt}
  else if(t === 'log'){log();}
  else if(t === 'datetime'){console.log(customtext, datetime, consoletext)}
  // else if(t === 'clear'){console.log('\033[2J');}
  else if(t == 'reload'){}
  else{console.log("\x1b[31m", "Неизвестная команда." + "\x1b[33m", "Для помощи: help" + "\x1b[0m")}
});
```

Консоль сервера: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто-то знает причину в этом, то пожалуйста обьясните, где ошибка.

---

А что нужно сделать, чтобы уходил? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ваш запрос `https://jide.cf/css/normal.css` не уходит дальше `nginx`

Comment: А что нужно сделать, чтобы запрос уходил?